# Is there a way to hide header and footer in a pdf file created with FPDF in PHP?

Tags: php, pdf, fpdf

I have created a pdf file with FPDF in PHP. When i insert the header and footers in it, they automatically gets displayed on all the pages of the pdf file. But i want to stop these header and footer from getting displayed on the first page and display them starting from the second page of the pdf file. I have searched the net but unable to find a solution.

In other words i want to dynamically create a cover page for the pdf report i have created with FPDF.

Can anybody give me some tips on how to perform this task of hidinh header and footer from the first page in pdf file!

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Mind you, this is merely something off the top of my head, but you need to tell the script, what you want it to show in the header/footer, right? Simply check what page you're on and tell it 'don't do a thing'?

Comment: Alternatively, you could create a PDF file without the first page, then add the header/footer. Save the file and then use FPDF to add a new first page.

Comment: Terry Seidler can you kindly clearify it a bit more that is it is possible to create a pdf file with out header and footer but dont save it on hard disk and then add new pages to it with header and footers

Answer (score 15, accepted):

That's an easy task. Try the following:

```
class PDF extends FPDF {
    ...

    function Header() {
        if ( $this->PageNo() !== 1 ) {
            // Add your stuff here
        }
    }

    function Footer() {
        if ( $this->PageNo() !== 1 ) {
            // Add your stuff here
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The problem is the Footers are created in Close() method at line 288 which is called from Output() at line 987 what means you're effectively turning the Footer off and then on just to display it anyways. What I would do if I needed the flexibility is something like:

```
class PDF extends FPDF {
    function Header() {
        if (!isset($this->header[$this->page]) || !$this->header[$this->page]) {
            // ...
        }
    }

    function Footer() {
        if (!isset($this->footer[$this->page]) || !$this->footer[$this->page]) {
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

and then use it like:

```
$pdf->header[1] = false;
$pdf->footer[1] = false;
$pdf->AddPage();

$pdf->header[2] = true;
$pdf->footer[2] = true;
$pdf->AddPage();
```

It might be not the most elegant solution, but it works and it effectively allows you to change the visibility of the footers dynamically (p.s.: not specifying the state would also leave you with headers on effectively reducing the amount of code you need)

Comment: This is old, but I think you mean for the if statements to read `!isset($this->header[$this->page]) || $this->header[$this->page]`.  Never the less I found this answer very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to add an answer for people coming here that don't want to skip the first, but the last (or any) page. Especially handy if you have dynamically changing text and cant foresee page numbers.
This can be done by setting a boolean while adding the page to the PDF.

Define your Header / Footer as

```
class PDF extends FPDF {
    function Header() {
        if (!$this->skipHeader) {
            // ...
        }
    }

    function Footer() {
        if (!$this->skipFooter) {
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

Then, when initializing the pdf make sure to set these bools to false, so you will get headers/footers in general.

```
$pdf = new PDF();
$pdf->skipHeader = false;
$pdf->skipFooter = false;
```

Once you actually want to skip a Header or Footer, set the respective bool to true

```
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->skipHeader = true;
$pdf->AddPageContents();
```

Remember to set them back to false if you want headers/footers on the next page!

Answer (score 0):

As an extension of what Paul's said, the footer is rendered after any content, so set `skipFooter` to `true` after rendering content.

```
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->skipHeader = true;
$pdf->AddPageContents();
$pdf->skipFooter = true;
```