# Customize header and footer in phptopdf creation

Tags: php

I am creating the PDF of the report using the internal url. (Reference site http://phptopdf.com)
I am using ("footer" => "Page phptopdf_on_page_number of phptopdf_pages_total") in $pdf_options array to display page number's at the bottom of the page.
In my report I dont need the page number on my first page, It should start diplaying the page number from second page of report.

Is that any way to do this?

Your help is greatly appreciated!!

Comment: you can put a custom condition for checking wether the page number is 1, if it is than don't echo it...

Comment: yeah.. I checked the docs from your link, are you not able to use your custom footer? in their docs there is no any `forloop` or `while loop` for pages, so you will not be able to do it using their constant.. you have to put your manual code..

Comment: If I would give manually the page number like
"footer" => '1' it would take 1 to all the pages because there is no way to increment the number. It is taking the footer all at once and than generate the PDF.

Comment: I installed the library in my pc and tried it, I think it will be very tough to remove paging from the first page, if you check their class file, they are creating the PDF on their server, some of the functions are coming from their live links, so we dont have that much rights to edit their default funnctions,but still you can use `FPDF` library to create PDFs,from this link http://www.fpdf.org/en/download.php,  and yes this can be the answer of your que http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11947692/is-there-a-way-to-hide-header-and-footer-in-a-pdf-file-created-with-fpdf-in-php

Comment: but still giving a try to `CSS3` or `php regular expressions` can work, but it will take a lot time. if you are able to take get the first footer DIV, than you can hide it with CSS, or by using `php regex or string function` you can replace the first footer text with blank space....